# How am I supposed to log exceptions with Fabric

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Now, where ever I used to have

```
Crashlytics.logException(e);
```

I'm getting an error similar to

```
The type io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   MonthlyOffer.java   /JOM Android Phone App/src/joelosteen/android/phone/JOMApp/layout   line 234    Java Problem
```

So are we not able to use logException with fabric?

** EDIT **

Thanks to sublime text 3 I did a `find in files...` and commented out every occorrence of lines with fabric or crashlytics in them:

- find: `(.*[fabric|crashlytics].*)`
- in: `*` (make sure this is your src folder)
- replace: `// $1`

** EDIT **

Using Eclipse v4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Android Studio. Are you using the latest version of Fabric (2.3.2 as of this writing)? Did the Fabric plugin add the necessary changes to your project?

You can log exceptions by using the logException method as outlined [here](https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/android/caught-exceptions)

Comment: Did the plugin make the necessary changes to your project?

Comment: It said it did, but no changes were made. I've manually had to make every change so far.

Comment: It seems as thought it might not have gotten integrated correctly in Eclipse. If you try it in a new project does it work? I'd try removing the plugin and re-installing it again by following the steps on the Fabric page: https://fabric.io/downloads